# A question about monotonic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are both continuous and monotonic , the $f+g$ is monotonic

So this clear when both are monotonic and continuous then $f+g$ is monotonic

**Note: the above is false.**

but what if neither $f,g$  are monotonic then is $f+g$ is monotonic

Comment: $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=-x$ are monotonic. Is $f+g$ monotonic?

Comment: first statement is not true if "monotonic" is interpreted as either monotone decreasing or monotone increasing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson..sorry i got $f+g$ is not monotonic , monotonic only applicable when non-decreasing is right

Comment: Please edit the body of the question, then, so it doesn't make false statements.

Comment: Never mind, I did it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be. Consider
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} -x, & x\leq 0\\ 3x,&x>0\end{cases},\qquad g(x) = \begin{cases} 3x, & x\leq 0\\ -x,&x>0\end{cases} $$
Both $f$ and $g$ are not monotonic, but $(f+g)(x) = 2x$ obviously is.

If $f$ is not monotonic then take $g=f$ and you'll see that $f+g=2f$ is not monotonic, as well.

Comment: In the definitions of $f$ and $g$ you mean $x>0$ for the second case, right?

Comment: Of course, thank you. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Let h be monotonic. Let f be any function at all .Let g=h-f.

Comment: $g$ might be monotonic though.